# Biometrics FingerPrint Java

Tags: java, database

I am trying to develop a java application which include finger print recognition. I need to store finger print to database.

Comment: it is an offtopic here. Use google to find answers to this question.

Comment: Would you be so kind to specify what you want help with ?

Comment: i want finger print details to database

Comment: you should improve your question's content. Did you read the information from the finger print? How's your fingerprint information available in your program? What DB you want to use?

Comment: i want use Mysql database .I want save finger print to database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem in using Java. But it needs both hardware and software support. You need a fingerprint scanner, check/ask your manufacturer, if they provide the API for Java. If you want to develop a mobile application, then I have doubt, if you really need to store the fingerprints as I don't think Apple/Samsung is going to provide you those. They provides API for that and all you need is to implement those API in your program.

If you want to store the fingerprint information's in a database, then you have several choices:

1. If your fingerprint collection is small, then just storing it in a Treemap will be enough instead of using a database. It will increase the performance of the application as there will be no need to retrieve data from the database. For a fingerprint application, performance matters.
2. However, for big number of collections, you can use relational databases like Mysql or others. For accessing relational databases, Java provides an API for database access, called JDBC.

Checkout these links for more about JDBC:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity

So, you have freedom to choose your preferred database. Even Mysql is enough to store the fingerprints data.

Comment: could you please recommend a product ? i am familiar with jdbc concepts

Comment: I will suggest Mysql database, because its much easier to learn, widely used and can does everything that you need.